# Linq Query for Complex Object

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Everyone - I have the following set of objects:

`User { String:Name, List<Devices> }`
`Device {String:Name, DeviceVariationInfo }`
`DeviceVariationInfo { String:OS }`

In the database those object are split into the following tables: 
Users, Devices, DevieVariationsInfo, UserToDevices

I am trying to query the the list of devices along with their variation info for a certain user, and am using the following query, which always returns a list of 0 items in `Devices`. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong here.. =)

```
 private void GetUserDevices(ref User user)
    {
        User locUSer = user; 

        if (user != null)
        {
            var deviesQuery = from dts in _dataConext.DB_UserToDevices
                              where dts.UserId == locUSer.Id
                              join ds in _dataConext.DB_Devices on dts.DeviceID equals ds.Id
                              join dsv in _dataConext.DB_DeviceVariations on ds.Id equals dsv.DeviceId
                              select new Device
                              {
                                  Version = ds.Version,
                                  VariationInfo = new DeviceVariation
                                  {
                                      OSVersion = dsv.OS
                                  },
                                  Name = ds.FriendlyName,
                                  Id = ds.Id
                              };

            if (deviesQuery != null)
                user.Devices = deviesQuery.ToList(); 

        }

    }
```

Comment: "I am trying to query the the lost of devices along with their variation info" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Also, note that deviesQuery will never return null. The query may return zero results, but the query object itself will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

Is User a class? If so, why are you passing it into GetUserDevices by `ref`? Don't do that unless you want to change the meaning of that reference.

Also, why are you doing this? `User locUSer = user;`

Here's how I'd go about debugging your problem: remove parts of that query until you get data back. For example, remove the last join statement, rerun the query, and see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Judah. Yes, 'User' is a class. And the reason am passing it by ref is because I fill populate the list of devices for that user object. The reason am assigning it to a local variable is because ref variable cannot be used inside the query.

Comment: If you're just filling user.Devices, you dont' have to pass it in by ref. Because it's a class, it's passed in by ref automatically; modifying it will modify the thing you passed in.

Comment: Have you tried removing some of the joins in order to find out where your query is going wrong?

Comment: What's the drawback for keeping this as a ref parameter?

Comment: The reason you should remove ref is the same reason that a drawing should have no unnecessary lines and a machine no unnecessary parts.